# Получить значения из TextBox в WPF с паттерном MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

мне необходимо получить данные из TextBox на форме

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Login ,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Password,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Добавляю Bynding, и связываю окно с ApplicationViewModel

```
 DataContext = new ApplicationViewModel();
```

И принять их в ApplicationViewModel применяя паттерн MVVM.

```
// Login
    public RelayCommand LoginWindow
    {
        get
        {
            return loginWindow ??
              (loginWindow = new RelayCommand((selectedItem) =>
              {
                  LoginAccount loginAccount = selectedItem as LoginAccount;
              }));
        }
    }
```

С WPF работаю впервые, подскажите, как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Ну так вы привязываете к свойствам `Login` и `Password`, они должны находится в классе, который указан как DataContext.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ наверное там и есть, но я использую MVVM и отправляю сначала в RelayCommand public void Execute(object parameter) где Parameter ничего не примет, и во ViewModel соот-но ничего нет